# Discussion: CMSIS VS Hardware Abstraction Layer by method of Texas Instruments

Tags: hardware, layer, abstraction, cmsis

I have used TI TMS320 MCUs for years. TI provides header and source files for accessing hardware. TI Implements a hardware abstraction layer to do that as you probably know.

ARM micro-controllers come with CMSIS, an standard for hardware abstraction layer.

I want to know your opinion; which method do you prefer?

I am very convenient with th TIs one. This is simple and understandable.

regards,

Ras

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMSIS and manufacturer HAL are not exlusive. Usually you will use both. ARM supplies the CMSIS to set up the ARM core, such as the NVIC (Nested Vector Interrupt Controller). The microcontroller manufacturer supplies HAL for the additional peripherals (such as I2C, UART...).

Comment: accurately, ARM provides templates to vendors. Vendors complete the header and source files in CMSIS format.